# My Windows 10 Won't Start Up: Error

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I wasn't on my laptop for about a week, I decided to start it up again.

It was on the Lenovo loading screen, but then it stopped loading; it was still on the Lenovo screen. Then, after 20 minutes, it said Preparing Automatic Repair at the bottom, under Lenovo TM. It then went to the blue screen, and said the following in this order:

```
Recovery
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
A required device isnt connected or can't be accessed.
Error code: 0xc0000185
You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or a USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/device manufacturer.
Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for startup settings
Press Esc for Firmware Settings
```

And that's it. Any help?

Comment: Did the laptop come with an installation/repair disc, and (if so) do you have it still?  If not, you should be able to contact Lenovo for a repair disc to repair Windows.

You can also use the repair menu by pressing F8 and using startup repair.

Comment: It sounds like your Windows Installation Drive is corrupt or missing. Do you force-shutdown your laptop often (Holding the power button)? Did you drop your laptop at any point while it was on or off? Can you hear your harddrive spinning up when you boot your PC? Does your harddrive make any loud clicking sounds when you try to boot your machine?